# Decoding text in PHP not decode

Tags: php, html, mysql, urlencode, urldecode

So. I have three massive texts from WYSIWYG editor that I need to store in DB (MySQL). To do that I use PHP function `rawurlencode()` put them in one array and `serialize()` the array, then insert into DB. But the problem is when I need to `rawurldecode()`.

First I `unserialize()` then text decodes normally, but image tag decodes like this:

```
`<img alt="\"\"" src="\"/ckfinder/userfiles/images/facebook.PNG\"" 
 style="\"float:right;" height:200px; width:198px\">`
```

there is multiple these ->`\"` that I dont need and in fact they don't appear in code that is not encoded. `str_replace()` won't help.

Maybe I do something wrong and there is better way how to store long texts in serialized array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `stripcslashes()` function available by default in PHP.
It will remove the backslashes that are added as escape characters.
[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_stripcslashes.asp)